# Import path missing after update angular 7 to 8

Tags: angular, sass, angular7, materialize, angular8

I have a "styles.scss" written in this way, working fine in Angular 7 version:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";

 @import "~materialize-css/sass/components/_color.scss";
@import './colors';

$roboto-font-path: "~materialize-css/dist/fonts/roboto/";
@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize";

/* isso aqui serve para o datepicker funcionar com modal do materialize ou mesmo bootstrap*/
.cdk-overlay-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1090;
  }
```

After I update to the version 8, the angular is not finding the correct path, I'm receving the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--13-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

 @import "~materialize-css/sass/components/_color.scss";
        ^
      Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
4 │  @import "~materialize-css/sass/components/_color.scss";
  │          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  stdin 4:10  root stylesheet
      in D:\angular_projects\inteligencia-web\src\styles.scss (line 4, column 10)
```

I've figured out that the angular is not understanding this path, that points to the node_modules folder. What I have to change?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that by one of these versions, the regular sass implementation is used, not the node-sass anymore to which we are used. Here, you find more about it: https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/2101.
For a first make-it-work, you can go back to node-sass by:

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

Answer (score -2):

Please be ensure that if your app makes use of Angular Material, you’ll want to follow with this command:

```
$ ng update @angular/material.
```

if it wont works then can you please share the steps you followed to upgrade